# Where to put things in docker containers?

Tags: linux, docker

I've been working with dockerized application for a while and I still was not able to figure out if there is a proper way to structure code in a container.

Several different packages use several approaches:

- Postgres follows more traditional way and stores data in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`
- Redis cares less about unix directory structure and puts persistant data into `/data` folder, but when it comes to the configuration it adheres: `/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf`
- Node encourages to put the application data into `/usr/src/app` and when using docke-compose they mention `/home/node/app` What...?
- PHP does something similar for CLI apps and for web they go with the usual `/var/www/html`

Where it comes to entrypoint scripts the issue is similar one put it into `/` others do put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

I hope you get my confusion.

Containers are supposed to be running single main process that they represent and when this process stops, they die. Is it reasonable to threat it like a full-blown linux system and adhere to the recommended way of structuring things? And if so, should i go with `/bin`, `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` for shell scripts and `/var/lib/app`, `/lib/app` or maybe `/usr/src/app` for application code? Or is the truth somewhere between and the `/entrypoint.sh` script is also ok?

Comment: To preface my comment, I am no expert, but I have been using Docker for a couple years. I have always just used the guidelines for the image that I am using, which may be different depending on the flavor of the OS. I am not aware of any sort of universal guideline established by Docker itself.

Comment: That's what I usually do too. But I find myself often creating new docker images and dockerizing (is that even a word?) many applications and pretty much every time I hesitate a little where to put entrypoint script and where to put the application code and so on. I often need to look back to how I did that in the previous project, because there are no established habits or guidelines in the back of my mind.